# FTPSClient failing to connect

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have been trying to change a working FTP connection FTPClient to a FTPSClient provided by apache. The only changes made were changing the class and indicating what port the application is going to connect.
The server connects to another server within the same network. For external servers, a proxy is required.

I already tried setting up the constructor to true, it shows the following message:

> Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

```
final FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient( true );
//same results
//final FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient("SSL", true );
//final FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient("TLS", true );
ftp.setDefaultPort(22);
```

When I set it up to false, the connection hangs up for a lot of time. It shows the following message:

> Could not parse response code. Server Reply: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.1

and tomcat shows the following page:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>   The proxy server could not handle the request POST /myapppath/APage.htm.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

```
final FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient( false );
ftp.setDefaultPort(22);
```

I tried connecting manually with WinSCP via SFTP and the connection is successful.

Answer (score 1):

FTPS (FTP over SSL/TLS) is not the same as SFTP (SSH file transfer); these are two completely different protocols. The reason you are getting the error `Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?` is because you are not connecting to a FTPS server.

[You can read more about the difference here.](https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/4672.php?page=all) If you want to make an SFTP connection rather than an FTPS connection, I would recommend using the [JSch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).